# How to calculate the distance between pedestrians and vehicles in each frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matlab, computer-vision

I have data from a drone. The first table has the pedestrians' data in each frame. The pedestrians' data has the pedestrian Id, frame, x_est, y_est, v_abs.
The second table is the vehicles' data. The vehicles' data has the vehicle Id, frame, x_est, y_est, vel_est.
For example, in frame number 1, I have 39 pedestrians and two vehicles. I want to create a new table that has the following information:

1. the first column is the distance between each pedestrian and every vehicle in each frame.
   For example, I have 39 pedestrians and 2 vehicles:

   d1 = sqrt((ped1_x - veh1_x)^2 + (ped1_y - veh1_y)^2)

   d2 = sqrt((ped1_x - veh2_x)^2 + (ped1_y - veh2_y)^2)

   d3 = sqrt((ped2_x - veh1_x)^2 + (ped2_y - veh1_y)^2)

   d4 = sqrt((ped2_x - veh2_x)^2 + (ped2_y - veh2_y)^2)

and so on

2. the second and third columns are the associated speed of the pedestrian and vehicles.
   For example, if i get d1 then I have to include the speed of ped1 and speed of veh1.
   If i get d2, then I have to include the speed of ped1 and speed of veh2 and so on.

I have 116 frames. I want to write code in python or Matlab to do these tasks. I tried python with the following code but didn't work because the vehicles' data has 182 rows and the pedestrians' data has 3950:

```
if peds["frame"] == vehs["frame"]:
    distance = math.sqrt(((peds.x_est-vehs.x_est)**2)+((peds.y_est - vehs.y_est))**2)
```

I'm thinking to add a for loop to loop over each frame. **How to modify the code to loop over each frame and calculate the distances between these objects?**

***This is an example of the data.***

**Pedestrians data:**
**id**
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39

**frame**
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

**x_est**
15.31251243
14.62957291
14.81940554
16.261254
14.25065235
13.71913744
12.77037156
11.82149333
11.02452266
10.4550769
9.962500442
10.56845947
11.17672903
11.70758495
14.28816743
13.41605196
11.6316746
11.4797624
13.3395301
10.98651306
11.89763531
12.46714593
13.90898049
11.17611058
9.20275126
11.10086732
11.66968305
12.88437259
13.37708455
14.17485782
14.81943565
15.65388549
17.7046208
18.76703333
19.22188971
19.03219028
19.63930168
19.26095788
20.54963754
21.87812196

**y_est**
24.04146967
23.85122822
22.59973819
21.46111998
22.25845431
22.52372129
22.37086056
22.82695733
22.7892778
22.78941678
21.42243054
21.49884121
21.46045752
21.53683577
19.86642817
19.75351002
19.29791125
17.24875682
16.56578255
14.97104209
10.11358571
9.733765266
9.165258769
8.102246321
8.216836276
6.659910277
6.774266283
2.865368769
3.05553263
4.459266668
4.193704362
4.420605884
4.26981189
3.547987191
4.042100815
4.876447865
5.294238544
6.090777216
3.966160063
4.762697865

**v_abs**
2.459007157
2.654334571
3.315403455
3.389573803
3.378566929
3.045539512
3.23011785
2.925099475
2.584998721
2.901642056
2.811892448
2.151019342
1.96347414
1.500567927
3.540985451
2.709992115
3.267972565
3.395063149
2.721779676
4.012212099
0.880854234
0.813933137
0.704372621
0.912089788
0.549592663
3.007799428
1.978963898
3.44757396
3.15737162
3.529382782
3.5556166
3.409764593
1.170765247
1.580709745
1.085228781
0.922279132
0.802698916
1.875894301
0.804975425
1.205954878

**Vehicles data:**

**id**
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901
900
901

**frame**
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
8
8
9
9
10
10
11
11
12
12
13
13
14
14
15
15
16
16
17
17
18
18
19
19
20
20

**x_est**
13.12181538
20.79676544
13.01830532
20.73447182
12.92056089
20.65301595
12.77984823
20.52422202
12.67147093
20.45207468
12.56504216
20.34050999
12.45704283
20.23392863
12.35122477
20.13000728
12.24825411
20.03070371
12.15111691
19.9359101
12.04685347
19.8497257
11.93870377
19.7593045
11.82507185
19.66695714
11.70785362
19.57813133
11.60090539
19.48509113
11.48174963
19.39305883
11.36790853
19.29876475
11.26066404
19.21938896
11.14538066
19.12658484
11.02149472
19.02832259

**y_est**
12.48631346
12.04945225
12.50757522
12.09243053
12.53150136
12.14119099
12.56295128
12.20178773
12.59034906
12.22451609
12.60945482
12.2800529
12.61885415
12.31947563
12.62842376
12.35799492
12.64016339
12.40403046
12.66696466
12.44343686
12.67398026
12.4828893
12.69217314
12.52761456
12.70404418
12.56747969
12.71201387
12.60893079
12.7352435
12.65130145
12.75948092
12.68935761
12.77039761
12.72362537
12.78182668
12.76864139
12.80477996
12.80719663
12.82141401
12.8529026

**vel_est**
2.607251494
2.480379041
2.607160714
2.479543211
2.60660445
2.478939563
2.60984436
2.482517229
2.610124888
2.479412431
2.610034708
2.481993315
2.609925021
2.483303075
2.609504867
2.484305008
2.608686875
2.485197239
2.607293512
2.485028991
2.606477634
2.483509058
2.60665034
2.483007857
2.607657856
2.482442343
2.609280114
2.481348408
2.609374438
2.481088229
2.612094232
2.480242567
2.613246915
2.479486909
2.612946522
2.476581726
2.614972124
2.475903808
2.618889831
2.47716006

Thanks in advance

Comment: A/ provide hérihule dataframe, B/ provide data (pedestian and vehicule) (and results) in text form, not images.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated it.

Comment: explain why you struggle with the assignment

Comment: So, you want the output to have 5 columns: ped no (0), car no (900), distance (11.76), ped velocity (2.459) and car velocity (2.607)?  Is that right?  That's easy to do.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Yeah. Five columns are great. Ped no, car no, the distance between each car in a frame and each pedestrian in the same frame, ped vel, and car vel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think through the problem in words.  For each pedestrian entry, for each car entry, if the frame number matches, compute the distance between them, and add a new row.  Nothing to it.

```
ped_id =  "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39"

ped_frame = "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1"

ped_x_est = "15.31251243 14.62957291 14.81940554 16.261254 14.25065235 13.71913744 12.77037156 11.82149333 11.02452266 10.4550769 9.962500442 10.56845947 11.17672903 11.70758495 14.28816743 13.41605196 11.6316746 11.4797624 13.3395301 10.98651306 11.89763531 12.46714593 13.90898049 11.17611058 9.20275126 11.10086732 11.66968305 12.88437259 13.37708455 14.17485782 14.81943565 15.65388549 17.7046208 18.76703333 19.22188971 19.03219028 19.63930168 19.26095788 20.54963754 21.87812196"

ped_y_est = "24.04146967 23.85122822 22.59973819 21.46111998 22.25845431 22.52372129 22.37086056 22.82695733 22.7892778 22.78941678 21.42243054 21.49884121 21.46045752 21.53683577 19.86642817 19.75351002 19.29791125 17.24875682 16.56578255 14.97104209 10.11358571 9.733765266 9.165258769 8.102246321 8.216836276 6.659910277 6.774266283 2.865368769 3.05553263 4.459266668 4.193704362 4.420605884 4.26981189 3.547987191 4.042100815 4.876447865 5.294238544 6.090777216 3.966160063 4.762697865"

ped_v_abs = "2.459007157 2.654334571 3.315403455 3.389573803 3.378566929 3.045539512 3.23011785 2.925099475 2.584998721 2.901642056 2.811892448 2.151019342 1.96347414 1.500567927 3.540985451 2.709992115 3.267972565 3.395063149 2.721779676 4.012212099 0.880854234 0.813933137 0.704372621 0.912089788 0.549592663 3.007799428 1.978963898 3.44757396 3.15737162 3.529382782 3.5556166 3.409764593 1.170765247 1.580709745 1.085228781 0.922279132 0.802698916 1.875894301 0.804975425 1.205954878"

veh_id = "900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901 900 901"

veh_frame = "1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 10 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17 18 18 19 19 20 20"

veh_x_est = "13.12181538 20.79676544 13.01830532 20.73447182 12.92056089 20.65301595 12.77984823 20.52422202 12.67147093 20.45207468 12.56504216 20.34050999 12.45704283 20.23392863 12.35122477 20.13000728 12.24825411 20.03070371 12.15111691 19.9359101 12.04685347 19.8497257 11.93870377 19.7593045 11.82507185 19.66695714 11.70785362 19.57813133 11.60090539 19.48509113 11.48174963 19.39305883 11.36790853 19.29876475 11.26066404 19.21938896 11.14538066 19.12658484 11.02149472 19.02832259"

veh_y_est = "12.48631346 12.04945225 12.50757522 12.09243053 12.53150136 12.14119099 12.56295128 12.20178773 12.59034906 12.22451609 12.60945482 12.2800529 12.61885415 12.31947563 12.62842376 12.35799492 12.64016339 12.40403046 12.66696466 12.44343686 12.67398026 12.4828893 12.69217314 12.52761456 12.70404418 12.56747969 12.71201387 12.60893079 12.7352435 12.65130145 12.75948092 12.68935761 12.77039761 12.72362537 12.78182668 12.76864139 12.80477996 12.80719663 12.82141401 12.8529026"

veh_vel_est = "2.607251494 2.480379041 2.607160714 2.479543211 2.60660445 2.478939563 2.60984436 2.482517229 2.610124888 2.479412431 2.610034708 2.481993315 2.609925021 2.483303075 2.609504867 2.484305008 2.608686875 2.485197239 2.607293512 2.485028991 2.606477634 2.483509058 2.60665034 2.483007857 2.607657856 2.482442343 2.609280114 2.481348408 2.609374438 2.481088229 2.612094232 2.480242567 2.613246915 2.479486909 2.612946522 2.476581726 2.614972124 2.475903808 2.618889831 2.47716006"

import math
import pandas as pd

def convert(s,cvt):
    return [cvt(k) for k in s.split()]

peds = list(zip( 
    convert(ped_id,int),
    convert(ped_frame,int),
    convert(ped_x_est,float),
    convert(ped_y_est,float),
    convert(ped_v_abs,float)
))

cars = list(zip( 
    convert(veh_id,int),
    convert(veh_frame,int),
    convert(veh_x_est,float),
    convert(veh_y_est,float),
    convert(veh_vel_est,float)
))

newdata = []
for ped in peds:
    for car in cars:
        if ped[1] != car[1]:
            continue
        dist = math.sqrt((ped[2]-car[2])**2 + (ped[3]-car[3])**2)
        newdata.append( (ped[0], car[0], dist, ped[4], car[4]) )

df = pd.DataFrame( newdata, columns=("ped id", "car id", "distance", "ped vel", "car vel"))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    ped id  car id   distance   ped vel   car vel
0        0     900  11.760986  2.459007  2.607251
1        0     901  13.186566  2.459007  2.480379
2        1     900  11.464494  2.654335  2.607251
3        1     901  13.316012  2.654335  2.480379
4        2     900  10.254910  3.315403  2.607251
..     ...     ...        ...       ...       ...
75      37     901   6.153415  1.875894  2.480379
76      38     900  11.303343  0.804975  2.607251
77      38     901   8.087069  0.804975  2.480379
78      39     900  11.675921  1.205955  2.607251
79      39     901   7.366554  1.205955  2.480379

[80 rows x 5 columns]
```